# How to complete missing factor levels in data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

Lets pretend I have something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
      PERSON = c("Peter", "Peter", "Marcel" , "Lisa", "Lisa"),        
      FRUIT = c("Apple", "Peach","Apple", "Apple", "Peach" ), 
      A = c(100, 200, 100, 200, 300), 
      B=c(1,2,3,4,5) )
df$PERSON <- as.factor(df$Person)
df$FRUIT <- factor(df$FRUIT, levels = c("Apple", "Peach", "Coconut"))
```

Which resulsts in

```
str(df): 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  4 variables:
$ PERSON: Factor w/ 3 levels "Lisa","Marcel",..: 3 3 2 1 1
$ FRUIT : Factor w/ 3 levels "Apple","Peach",..: 1 2 1 1 2
$ A     : num  100 200 100 200 300
$ B     : num  1 2 3 4 5
```

I want to expand this data, frame so that for every PERSON there are all levels of FRUIT present, like this:

```
 Person FRUIT   A B
1  Peter Apple 100 1
2  Peter Peach 200 2
3  Peter Coconut 0 0
4 Marcel Apple 100 3
5 Marcel Peach 0 0
6 Marcel Coconut 0 0
7   Lisa Apple 200 4
8   Lisa Peach 300 5
9   Lisa Coconut 0 0
```

Missing values for `A` and `B` should be filled with 0.

I tried `tidyr::complete(df$FRUIT, 0)`, but it seems, that I used this function wrong.

Comment: Correct with `df$PERSON <- as.factor(df$PERSON)`

Answer (score 16):

The `complete` takes the first argument as 'data', followed by the columns to expand.  By default, the `fill` is NA, but we can change it to 0 by specifying it in a `list`.

```
complete(df, PERSON, FRUIT, fill = list(A=0, B = 0))
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Is it also possible to build the list based on the column names? In the real world setting, the number of columns to be filled with 0 is 20. So there is a lot to type

Comment: @barracuda317  In that case try `complete_` i.e. `library(dplyr); complete_(df, names(df)[1:2]) %>% mutate_each(funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0)), A:B)`